# unable verify signature in dropbox in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox

i need code in node js for config post webhook in dropbox for if any event like add update delete happen in app of dropbox my webhook trigger and i want that meta data of file it mostly is image format is there any suggestion for this how do this

```
const express = require("express");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const app = express();
const dropboxV2Api = require("dropbox-v2-api");
const Dropbox = dropboxV2Api.authenticate({
  token:
    "token", // Replace with your actual access token
});
const redis = require("redis");
const { log } = require("console");
const markdownIt = require("markdown-it")();

const appSecret = "appSecret"; // Replace with your actual app secret
const APP_SECRET = appSecret.trim();

function verifySignature(signature, data) {
  const expectedSignature = crypto
  .createHmac("sha256", APP_SECRET)
  .update(data)
  .digest("hex");
  console.log('expectedSignature:-------- ', expectedSignature);
  const datas = crypto.timingSafeEqual(
    Buffer.from(signature, "utf-8"),
    Buffer.from(expectedSignature, "utf-8")
    );
    console.log('data:------- ', datas);
  return datas
}

const redisClient = redis.createClient();
```

function

```
async function processUser(account) {
  // Call /files/list_folder for the given user ID and process any changes.

  // OAuth token for the user
  const token = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    redisClient.get("tokens", account, (err, token) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(token);
    });
  });

  // cursor for the user (null the first time)
  let cursor = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    redisClient.get("cursors", account, (err, cursor) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(cursor);
    });
  });
  console.log('cursor:----- ', cursor);


  let hasMore = true;

  while (hasMore) {
    let result;

    if (!cursor) {
      result = await Dropbox({
        resource: "files/list_folder",
        parameters: {
          path: "",
        },
      });
    } else {
      result = await Dropbox({
        resource: "files/list_folder/continue",
        parameters: {
          cursor: cursor,
        },
      });
    }

    for (const entry of result.entries) {
      // Ignore deleted files, folders, and non-markdown files
      if (
        entry[".tag"] === "deleted" ||
        entry[".tag"] === "folder" ||
        !entry.path_lower.endsWith(".md")
      ) {
        continue;
      }

      // Convert to HTML
      const resp = await Dropbox({
        resource: "files/download",
        parameters: {
          path: entry.path_lower,
        },
      });
      const markdownContent = resp.fileBinary.toString("utf-8");
      const html = markdownIt.render(markdownContent);

      // Upload HTML content
      await Dropbox({
        resource: "files/upload",
        parameters: {
          path: entry.path_lower.slice(0, -3) + ".html",
          mode: { ".tag": "overwrite" },
        },
        readStream: Buffer.from(html, "utf-8"),
      });
    }

    // Update cursor
    cursor = result.cursor;
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      redisClient.hset("cursors", account, cursor, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        resolve();
      });
    });

    // Repeat only if there's more to do
    hasMore = result.has_more;
  }
}
```

this is end point
i use ngrok for live instead of localhost

```
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Get Webhook");
  // Respond to the webhook verification (GET request) by echoing back the challenge parameter.
  const challenge = req.query.challenge;

  res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
  res.send(challenge);
});

app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Post Webhook");
  console.log(req.body);

  const signature = req.headers["x-dropbox-signature"];
  console.log('signature: ', signature);
  console.log('JSON.stringify(req.body): ', JSON.stringify(req.body));

  if (!verifySignature(signature, JSON.stringify(req.body).trim())) {
    console.log("not verify");
    res.status(403).send("Forbidden");
    return;
  }

  const accounts = req.body.list_folder.accounts;
  console.log('accounts:----- ', accounts);

  accounts.forEach((account) => {
    console.log('account: --------', account);
    // Process user data
    setTimeout(() => {
      processUser(account);
    }, 0);
  });

  res.status(200).send("OK");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

this is my code